# Passing data between screens without changing screens in flutter

Tags: flutter, screen, navigator

I'm new to flutter guys and I'm creating a project where I have a menu screen and a main screen that shows all the orders of all the users connected together with a bottom navigation bar. Now I managed to transfer the data between the two screens successfully but I had to use Navigator.push so everytime I press the button it stacks the main screen on top of the menu screen instead of navigating to it from the bottom navigation bar. I searched a lot of questions but I haven't found an answer as to how I can pass the data but either remain on the same screen (Menu screen) or Navigate back to it without putting it on top of the other screen. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Here is my elevated button:

```
Center(
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).push(
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => Home(
                      firstItemOrders: firstItemOrders,
                      secondItemOrders: secondItemOrders,
                      thirdItemOrders: thirdItemOrders,
                      fourthItemOrders: fourthItemOrders,
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
              child: Text('Update order'),
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary: Colors.brown[400]),
            ),
          ),
```